# How to customize the Struts Json Plugin Date format for a global scope

Tags: json, struts2

As for the title.
I don't want to add an annotation(@Json(format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") on every getXXXDate(),can anybody give a solution?

Comment: I don’t think I understand the question. Are you looking for a global date formatter? Please clarify the question with additional context.

Comment: @johnnieb                                                             Yes, I am looking for a global date formatter.

Answer (score 6):

You can use struts 2 json plugins in object class, for example:

```
        private Date createdDate;

        @JSON(format="MM/dd/yyyy") 
  // or @JSON(format="date.format") from bundle resource properties files
        public Date getCreatedDate() {
            return createdDate;
        }

        public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
            this.createdDate = createdDate;
        }
```

Comment: best solution for my requirement which cant able to get in jsonplugin page. thanks @sonTL